# Ampersand Sass selector doesn't work with sibling selector in styled components

Tags: css, sass, styled-components

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const Styles = styled.div`
  .App {
    &__input {
      width: 200px;
      background-color: orangered;
      &:focus {
        background-color: greenyellow;
      }
    }
    &__button {
      background-color: grey;
    }
    /* this works */
    &__input:focus + .App__button {
      background-color: greenyellow;
    }

    /* this doesn't */
    &__input:focus + &__button {
      background-color: greenyellow;
    }
  }
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Styles>
      <div className="App">
        <input className="App__input" />
        <button className="App__button">click</button>
      </div>
    </Styles>
  );
}
```

As you can see in the code, I expect the `&` to refer to `.App` as it is working in other places as well as in node_sass.

Is this a bug in styled-components or am I missing something here?

Here is a [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-visvesvaraya-ibjd8?file=/src/App.js) to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe here is the problem:

> Because the parent selector could be replaced by a type selector like h1, it’s only allowed at the beginning of compound selectors where a type selector would also be allowed...

It also says:

> It can also be used to style the outer selector in a certain context...

It seems that it's not a suitable "context" in your case.

See the SASS Parent Selector docs. [here](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector).

### Edit

As we tested it on several contexts, different from `styled-components`, and it worked, the first option is confirmed:

It's a bug in `styled-components`.

Comment: The code I wrote above is working fine in node-sass package. I'm only getting this issue while using styled-components.

If you to write 
```
.search{
    &__input:focus + &__button {
      background-color: blue;
    }
}
``` on https://www.sassmeister.com/

Comment: Well, I also did tried it here tweaking some parameters, and again, it works as expected, then it's just a bug from styled-components. (Updated answer btw).